# Dynamic launch screen image?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib, launch-screen

With the (relatively) new feature of iOS to have launch screens generated from a XIB file, a logical question arises: is it possible to reference any sort of dynamic resource from these XIBs? An example would be an app having customisable home screen, which makes it neccessary for the XIB file to adjust once the user changes smth (i.e. background color)?

Maybe it's possible to reference an image from Documents/ folder or read some dynamic plist file's values?

Comment: You can't do anything dynamic with the launch screen

Answer (score 1):

According to iOS Human interface guideline Launch file/image should be static.

> Design a launch image that is identical to the first screen of the app, except for:
>
> - Text. The launch image is static, so any text you display in it won’t be localized.
> - UI elements that might change. If you include elements that might look different when the app
>     finishes launching, users can experience an unpleasant flash between
>     the launch image and the first app screen.

For more information see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html